# How can I use SSH aliases with rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I can successfully use command `ssh myVDShost` without password to connect my VDS host.

But when I use command `sudo rsync -azP myVDShost:/home/ /mnt/myextdisk` I get error:
`ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Name or service not known`

How can I use SSH aliases with rsync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no problems using `Host` aliases defined in `.ssh/config` with `rsync`. Perhaps you shouldn't be using the `sudo`, which might make SSH use `root`'s settings.

Comment: You are right. Without sudo rsync works well with aliases. ty

Comment: @Dimetry Without sudo rsync just uses regular user keys, not that of root's